# Drill Down Data Links In Grafana

Tags: grafana

I created a time series type graph in grafana i attached the screenshot of same

[image]

This Graph Shows How many Applications for some specific time range (Last 7 days, Last 6 months etc.) is created in my Web Application.

Now i added a data link to another dashboard which shows time series graph of Applications with their current status.

http://localhost:3000/d/gr7ZaMank/loan-application-by-status?orgId=1&var-status=All﻿&from=${__value.time}&to=${__to}

Now whenever i click a point on graph i am taking the time of that point in **from** parameter and in **to**  parameter i am taking the last time.

As far as i know the graph shows data which is grouped by time.

**Is there is any way to know how the date and time is grouped i break that date and pass it as a from and to in other dashboard for looking the acutal value of a point?**